# Need XPath to extract and rearrange data

Tags: xml, xpath, xquery, xpath-2.0, xmllint

I am trying to extract the data from xml document but I am failing to do it correctly.
Below is the sample xml data from which I need specific string details .

XML file

```
<BESAPI xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="BESAPI.xsd">
    <Action Resource="https://12.13.14.15:52311/api/action/38954" LastModified="Thu, 05 Apr 2018 19:28:54 +0000">
        <Name>*****HOSTING_Dump_SQL_Product_Keys*****</Name>
        <ID>38954</ID>
    </Action>
    <Action Resource="https://12.13.14.15:52311/api/action/40872" LastModified="Thu, 22 Jun 2023 18:42:33 +0000">
        <Name>POLICY - Run Capacity Scan and Upload Results - NoEND</Name>
        <ID>40872</ID>
    </Action>
<Action Resource="https://12.13.14.15:52311/api/action/40872" LastModified="Thu, 22 Jun 2023 18:42:33 +0000">
        <Name>PROD-TEST</Name>
        <ID>40872</ID>
    </Action>
<Action Resource="https://12.13.14.15:52311/api/action/40873" LastModified="Thu, 22 Jun 2023 18:42:33 +0000">
        <Name>PROD-TEST</Name>
        <ID>40873</ID>
    </Action>
</BESAPI>
```

Now when I run from my MAC terminal the below command , it gives me the Name tag only but I want associated Resource="https:///...." value as well. Please help me formulate xpath query for the same.

```
xmllint --xpath "/BESAPI/Action/Name/text()" actions.xml | grep -i prod      
PROD-TEST
PROD-TEST
```

Desired Output

```
PROD-TEST - https://12.13.14.15:52311/api/action/40872
PROD-TEST - https://12.13.14.15:52311/api/action/40873
```

Also how to extract both Name and ID part in one XML query. Something like below output

```
PROD-TEST - 40872
PROD-TEST - 40873
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use a tool supporting current XPath 3.1/XQuery 3.1 you can use an expression like

```
/BESAPI/Action[Name = 'PROD-TEST']/(Name || ' - ' || ID)
```

There are lots of options to have XPath 3.1 support, if you have Node installed you could install the `xslt3` tool with npm and then use e.g. `xslt3 -s:actions.xml -xp:"/BESAPI/Action[Name = 'PROD-TEST']/(Name || ' - ' || ID)"`.

Comment: I tried the command but it is giving me below error . xmllint --xpath "/BESAPI/Action[Name='PROD-TEST']/(Name || ' - ' || ID)" actions.xml
XPath error : Invalid expression
/BESAPI/Action[Name='PROD-TEST']/(Name || ' - ' || ID)
                                     ^
XPath evaluation failure

Comment: @isilia, xmllint supports XPath 1.0 only, that is from 1999, the latest version is XPath 3.1 from 2017, as I said, you would need to install or at least use a different tool than the one you are currently using as XPath 1.0/xmllint don't have that expressive power and simpleness of XPath 3.1. If you have Node.js on your machine, you can install the `xslt3` tool https://www.npmjs.com/package/xslt3 with npm and use it as I have already shown in the answer.

Comment: Okay I will try to do that. I tried another command to get Resource string but how to remove "Resource=" from the output and only get the url . Any ideas about that? ```xmllint --xpath "/BESAPI/Action[Name='PROD-TEST']/@Resource" actions.xml 
 Resource="https://12.13.14.15:52311/api/action/10602879"
 Resource="https://12.13.14.15:52311/api/action/10603422"
```

Comment: @Isilia, I am willing to help you with an XPath 3 expression like e.g. `/BESAPI/Action[Name='PROD-TEST']/@Resource/string()` but as I said, xmllint and XPath 1.0 don't have much of an expressive power and given that there lots of tools implementing and support XPath 3.1 and/or XQuery 3.1 I would suggest to install one and then try to exploit the expressive power and compactness of the current version instead of trying to work around the shortcomings of antiquated versions and tools.